# is it possible to set linum-mode at startup of buffer?

Tags: linum-mode

I wonder if it is possible to set #+STARTUP: linum-mode t or similar at the start of the buffer (not interested in the global mode). I have tried this but it won't work. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Is this strictly an `org-mode` question?  If not, have you tried file-local variables?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the buffer:

```
# -*- eval: (linum-mode 1) -*-
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect! So I guess not all commands can be used with#+startup?

Comment: I'm not a big org user (I know I should); I don't know anything about `#+startup`.  This is just general file local variables.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein `#+STARTUP` has nothing to do with commands and is Org-specific. See [`(org) In-buffer settings`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/In_002dbuffer-settings.html).

Comment: Note also that Emacs 26 comes with native line numbering which can be enabled with just `# -*- display-line-numbers: t -*-`.